# Refraction of sound atomic level

Tags: waves, atomic-physics, acoustics, refraction

how the refraction of sound and the change in the angle of propagation can be explained at the atomic level, why the direction of propagation of molecules changes in different media?

Comment: Sound isn't an atomic level phenomenon.

Comment: To follow up on the previous comment, sound waves (by, essentially, definition) are *long-wavelength* waves, long-wavelength defined as "much larger than the interatomic spacing". That said, if you go from one medium to another, the molecules and their interatomic forces change, and so the "spring constant" of the "springs" connecting the molecules and the mass of the molecules change, and so the speed of sound (given schematically as $\sqrt{k/m}$, with modifications due to lots of springs and atoms) changes. A changing speed of waves causes refraction.

Comment: Also, the direction of sound propagation had nothing to do with "direction of propagation of molecules". There is no such thing in a sound wave.

Comment: I'm don't get this yet. I'm thinking i'm little confused . When a sound wave pass for example to air for water the angle of propagation changes . Why this happens . Maybe there will be a change in momentum . Like some parts are interfered destructively and other parts constructively . If there is happening how can explained with classic mechanics ? . When i refer momentum it's because i'm think in colision beteween molecules , and maybe some these colisions soffer interference, and for this the angle of propagation changes

Comment: Could you describe a sound wave when the medium comprises, let’s say, 5 molecules? If you could do that, you would be one step closer to solving your problem. The hard part here is that sound is described as the “behaviour” of a bunch of molecules and not just 10 or 20. Good luck with describing the molecule movement for 5 molecules reaching a wave equation-like solution. It won’t happen due to thermal/Brownian “noise”, on the contrary, when you consider a large number of molecules this averages out. This is what others defined in their comments about sound **not** being an atomic phenomenon.

Comment: So with that in mind, you shouldn’t treat sound down to the atomic level, because this is **not** what sound is.

Answer (score 1):

> how the refraction of sound and the change in the angle of propagation can be explained at the atomic level, why the direction of propagation of molecules changes in different media?

Sound is a molecular phenomenon. Molecules of air move and collide and momentum is conserved.
When sound passes from air to water, the speed of the sound wave increases since sound travels faster in water. But if the wave front hits the surface of the water at an angle then the leading edge of the wave will hit the water first, and begins to travel faster than the trailing edge of the wave still propagating through the air. This speed difference causes the wavefront to change angle until the full wavefront is in the water and then the wavefront will move with same velocity and continue in a straight line until next interface. Different materials have different speeds for sound so the refraction angle will be material-dependent.